# Showing an error while using XMLWorkerHelper

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I am trying to convert HTML data to PDF. For that I have used xmlworker-5.5.6.jar.
But while executing code its showing an error of missing resources.

Can anybody please help. 
Thanks in Advance.

Here is My Code

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(filepathpdf)));
document.open();
document.addAuthor("ME");
document.addCreator("ME");
document.addSubject("Thanks for your support");
document.addCreationDate();
document.addTitle("Please read this");
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
String str = sb.toString().substring(sb.indexOf("<html"),sb.length());
System.out.println(str);
worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, new StringReader(str));
document.close();
System.out.println("Done.");
```

And here is my error :

> 08-24 12:28:42.079 14077-15044/com.abc.abc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
>                                                                     Process: com.abc.abc, PID: 14077
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.net.FileRetrieveImpl.processFromHref(FileRetrieveImpl.java:170)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver.addCssFile(StyleAttrCSSResolver.java:404)
>                                                                         at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.head.Link.start(Link.java:80)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.startElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:131)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.open(HtmlPipeline.java:105)
>                                                                         at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.startElement(XMLWorker.java:103)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.startElement(XMLParser.java:372)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.SelfClosingTagState.process(SelfClosingTagState.java:71)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:237)
>                                                                         at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:215)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:174)
>                                                                         at
>   com.abc.abc.SearchDetailsActivity$DownloadFileAsync.doInBackground(SearchDetailsActivity.java:2316)
>                                                                         at
>   com.abc.abc.SearchDetailsActivity$DownloadFileAsync.doInBackground(SearchDetailsActivity.java:2177)
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                      Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for
>   bundle 'errors/errors_en_GB', key ''
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.missingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:238)
>                                                                         at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:230)
>                                                                         at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:159)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.LocaleMessages.(LocaleMessages.java:99)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.LocaleMessages.(LocaleMessages.java:84)
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.net.FileRetrieveImpl.processFromHref(FileRetrieveImpl.java:170) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver.addCssFile(StyleAttrCSSResolver.java:404) 
>                                                                         at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.head.Link.start(Link.java:80) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.startElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:131) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.open(HtmlPipeline.java:105) 
>                                                                         at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.startElement(XMLWorker.java:103) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.startElement(XMLParser.java:372) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.SelfClosingTagState.process(SelfClosingTagState.java:71) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:237) 
>                                                                         at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:215) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:174) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.abc.abc.SearchDetailsActivity$DownloadFileAsync.doInBackground(SearchDetailsActivity.java:2316) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.abc.abc.SearchDetailsActivity$DownloadFileAsync.doInBackground(SearchDetailsActivity.java:2177) 
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: `errors/errors_en_GB` doesn't exist in iText. We have error files in `com/itextpdf/text/I10n/`, more specifically `en.lng`, `nl.lng` and `pt.lng`. Are you using iText (the Java library) or iTextG (the Android port of the Java library)?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. I am using iText Java Library..

Comment: That's the library you use in Java applications. You are using iText on Android. In that case, you should use iTextG. iTextG is similar to iText, but all the references to forbidden classes in packages such as `java.awt` and `javax.nio` are removed. A simple class such as `java.awt.Color` can cause problems on Android, so please switch to iTextG.

Comment: Hello, I have removed Itext Java library and now added dependency     compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9' in my project. But still its showing same error. I am using xmlworker-5.4.1.jar. is it ok ??

Comment: The version numbers need to be in sync. If you use iTextG 5.5.9, you need XML Worker 5.5.9. This may not solve your problem (I think you are throwing away your resources when creating the APK), but it will solve other problems.